# After installing any theme, I face wp_includes problem in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes, warnings

After installing any theme in WordPress I face this issue:

```
Warning: An unexpected error occurred. 
Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server's configuration. 
If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums.(WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. 
Please contact your server administrator.) in C:\xampp\htdocs\my_wp\wp-includes\update.php on line 173
```

Comment: How are you hosting the site? check out this article possible solutions: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-secure-connection-error-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thank you sir for consuming time for the answer of my question. Sir but I am facing this issue on local host "xampp".